# identity server 4 using multiple external identity providers

Tags: identityserver4

I would like to use identity server 4 with a bunch of different external identity providers. Not just one. 
For example: one business might use ADFS for their EIP another will use AZURE identity and so on. In this scenario there would only be one instance of identity server accessing different External id providers.

Is this possible or has anyone ever tried this. If not, do you know of a service that does do this.

Answer (score 5):

Of course this is possible. You can register as many external IdP's in your Startup class as you like. Be sure to also check out the sample quickstart repositories from Identityserver.

This code will register AzureAd and Google as external IdP's.
In advance to set this up you will have to register your application in developers.google and AzureAd to authorize your application.

```
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
    {
        ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:clientid"],
        Authority = Configuration["AzureAd:authority"],
        ClientSecret = Configuration["AzureAd:secret"],
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/signed-out",
        AuthenticationScheme = "AzureAd",
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
        SaveToken = true,
    });

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
    {
        ClientId = Configuration["Google:clientid"],
        ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:secret"],
        AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
        SaveTokens = true
    });
```

Comment: anything to do with finbuckle?